# Can I integrate a bot into a zap in Zapier?

Tags: bots, zapier, webbot

I am looking to create a zap in Zapier that automates all of the preparations I do preceding a tutoring appointment.

I use [bitpaper.io](https://bitpaper.io) to create shared whiteboards, and would like to automate the process of creating a new whiteboard and sharing its URL.

Is it possible to integrate the code to do this into a zap? I understand that this would be possible independent of Zapier via python or JS.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that this would be possible independent of Zapier via python or JS

If you can do it in Python or JS, then at the very least, you can run that same Python/JS in Zapier.

You can do that either via a `Code by Zapier` action, or by wrapping your code in a [Zapier integration](https://platform.zapier.com/) so you can reuse it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Zapier in conjunction with no code browser automation tools like [Axiom.ai](https://axiom.ai/?ref=fso2) or [powerautomate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-us/); I made a quick video showing you [how to do this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fotigh1Sqj0)

This may be overkill but saves on coding.